# Autenticar Oauth2 y JWT

Tags: symfony, jwt, oauth2

estoy desarrollando una API y tengo la siguiente duda sobre la autenticación.

En principio a aplique JWT para autenticar un usuario. Por lo tanto desde una app mobile ingreso usuario y clave, genero el token jwt y luego accedo a todas las rutas en donde funciona todo perfecto.

Mi duda es la siguiente. Con JWT logro tener una autenticación pero no evito la restriccion de que consuman la API terceros, por lo tanto cualquier persona puede hacer llamados a la API sin estar autorizados. 
Y hay rutas que no requieren autenticacion por ejemplo la ruta que crea cuentas de usuarios.

Existe alguna forma de usar oauth2 para dar permiso a una app que utilice la API y el jwt para loguear un usuario al sistema?

Gracias.

Comment: Existe el fosoauthserverbundle. Podrías instalarlo en tu app, hacer el proceso de validación sobre ti mismo, y añadir una gran extensión para manejar los jwt...  Revisa el enlace https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/adding_grant_extensions.md, creo que puede ser lo que buscas

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta. Tanto si usas Oauth como si usas JWT el flujo es: 1.- loguearse para obtener el token, 2.- enviar el token en cada petición. Todas las rutas que requieren autenticación requieren el token (sea Oauth o JWT) y las que no, simplemente no comprobarán ninguno de los dos. La única diferencia es que con Oauth tienes que mantener los tokens generados en la BBDD, verificarlos en cada llamado al API y obtener los datos de usuario, mientras que el JWT se puede verificar en la petición misma y contiene toda la info del usuario sin que debas consultarla en BBDD.

Comment: También vale la pena mencionar que puedes generar un JWT para la app con una expiración de 25 años que quede permanentemente guardado y enviarla con otro header. (ej X-Authorization). Ese JWT no es para ningún usuario en particular, no contiene más que datos dummy pero es válido si está firmado con el mismo hash con que lo compruebas. Con eso, puedes hacer que los endpoints no autenticados lo verifiquen antes de proseguir.

Answer (score 1):

Intenté responder en los comentarios pero creo que no queda claro.

Primero: Definamos que la respuesta "**no autorizado**" se refiere a responder con un `header 401` y un mensaje de error del tipo: "*token no válido o expirado, inicie sesión*".

Tanto el flujo Oauth como el JWT siguen la misma lógica general:

1. Envío usuario y contraseña a un endpoint que no pide autenticación
2. Obtengo un `<token>`
3. La APP manda ese `<token>` en todas las peticiones en el header `Authorization`
4. El API valida ese `<token>` en los endpoints que requieren autenticación y si no es válido, responde **no autorizado**
5. Si es válido, obtiene con éste los datos del usuario y trabaja con ellos

Supongamos que en un BBDD tienes una tabla de usuarios con la estructura

```
id_user | password      | nombre |     email
-------------------------------------------------
     1  | $2y$10$pDweWy | pedro  | pedro@mail.com
     2  | $2y$10$l43VL1 | juan   | juan@mail.com
     3  | $2y$10$TJdiWI | diego  | diego@mail.com
```

## Con el flujo Oauth

tienes que mantener una tabla de tokens con la estructura (un ejemplo)

```
id_user |          password              | nombre |     email
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  | FPbDMzL3hoUkM4ME9aZW56eWF1abcd | pedro  | pedro@mail.com
     2  | ptTXJCTndPOE9ucElQa2ZtSXg2Ly5o | juan   | juan@mail.com
     3  | BkQjN1QkdINWFsS3hQUHA2QTU2QmVr | diego  | diego@mail.com
```

Luego el cliclo de vida del request es:

**Autenticación**

1. Envío una petición al endpoint de login
2. Si el usuario y contraseña no calzan, respondo **no autorizado**
3. Si calzan, genero un `<token>`, lo inserto en mi tabla de tokens y lo envío en la respuesta

La generación del token puede ser un string de X caracteres random, (encriptados opcionalmente con la función [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) para que sea imposible forjar un token artificialmente), y luego pasados por [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) para no tener problemas con caracteres especiales. En realidad, usarías una librería que manejara la generación de los tokens por ti, asi que puedes abstraerte de este problema.

**Llamadas a endpoints autenticados**

1. Recibo la petición. Si no tiene un header Authorization, respondo **no autorizado**
2. Si viene el header Authorization, su contenido es `<token>` y lo busco en mi tabla de tokens
3. Si no está, respondo **no autorizado**
4. Si está, obtengo de ella el id user y la expiración
5. Si está expirado, lo borro de la tabla y respondo **no autorizado**
6. Si no está expirado, busco el `id_user` en mi tabla de usuarios
7. Obtengo los datos de usuario y trabajo con ellos

## Con el flujo JWT

El flujo de autenticación es el mismo: usuario y password, si son correctos devuelvo un token `<token>`. La aplicación me mandará el token en el header `Authorization` con la forma `JWT <token>`.

Alguna librería habrá generado el token con la siguiente lógica

**generación del token**

1. Tengo una `<firma>` en la configuración de la aplicación o en una variable de entorno
2. Mi `<token>` tiene la forma `<x caracteres>`.`<info del usuario en base64>`.`<z caracteres>`
3. La librería genera un `<token>` tomando la info relevante del usuario,  añadiéndole una expiración y firmándolo con la `<firma>`. Esto lo hace la librería de JWT
4. El usuario recibe el `<token>` y en las peticiones subsecuentes lo envía en el header Authorization con el contenido `JWT <token>`.

Aunque es la librería la que se encarga de generar el token, para efectos ilustrativos lo que hace la librería de JWT por debajo es algo así como:

```
<?php

$firma=getenv('TOKEN_SECRET');

$info_relevante=[
    'id_user'=>1, 
    'nombre'=>'pedro', 
    'email'=> 'pedro@mail.com', 
    'expiracion'=>1531484696103
];

$parte_central = base64_encode(json_encode($info_relevante));
```

`<parte_central>` sería, en este caso

```
eyJpZF91c2VyIjoxLCJub21icmUiOiJwZWRybyIsImVtYWlsIjoicGVkcm9AbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHBpcmFjaW9uIjoxNTMxNDg0Njk2MTAzfQ==
```

La `<parte central>` contiene por sí misma la info del usuario

```js
var parte_central='eyJpZF91c2VyIjoxLCJub21icmUiOiJwZWRybyIsImVtYWlsIjoicGVkcm9AbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHBpcmFjaW9uIjoxNTMxNDg0Njk2MTAzfQ==';

var datos_usuario=JSON.parse(atob(parte_central));

console.log(datos_usuario);
```

La librería firma el token:

```
$token = funcion_firma_jwt($parte_central, $firma);
// forma del token: qwertyx.<parte_central>.asdfg_zxcvb
```

Lo que viene antes del primer punto y lo que viene después del segundo punto son el sello que permitirá validar que el token ha sido firmado con la misma `<firma>` de tu API.

**Llamadas a endpoints autenticados**

1. Recibo la petición. Si no tiene un header Authorization, respondo **no autorizado**
2. Si viene el header Authorization, su contenido es `JWT <token>`. Le quito los cuatro primeros caracteres "JWT ".
3. Le pido a la librería de JWT que verifique el `<token>` usando la `<firma>` que está en la configuración **sin necesidad de pegarle a la BBDD.**
4. Si la firma no es válida o el `<token>` está expirado, respondo **no autorizado**
5. Si es válido, la librería usará `base64_decode` sobre la `<parte central>` para saber el id, email y nombre del usuario **sin necesidad de pegarle a la BBDD**
6. La librería me entregó los datos del usuario y trabajo con ellos.

(es probable que la librería por sí misma se preocupe de remover el prefijo "JWT ")

## Conclusión

- **JWT** se comprueba al vuelo sin pegarle a la BBDD, pero debes tener una `<firma>` en tu config o variable de entorno
- **Oauth** no necesita una firma en la configuración, pero le pega a la BBDD en cada petición.

Como verás, el flujo es similar, salvo que con JWT no necesitas pegarle 
a la BBDD para verificar el token u obtener los datos del usuario. Todo viene en el token mismo.

## Endpoints no autenticados

Ahora bien, siempre tendrás algunos endpoints que no necesitan autorización. Un ejemplo podría ser un endpoint para comprobar que la API está arriba (algo como https://api.com/health) que no hace ningún daño.

Si quieres proteger los endpoints no autenticados para no aceptar peticiones de otras apps, en ambos casos la APP puede obtener un `<token>` por sí misma de manera que al pegarle a `/login` o `/register` validen el token de la APP antes de proseguir. Pero esa validación puede ser indistintamente JWT u Oauth. Si es lo segundo, de nuevo tienes que pegarle a la BBDD para validar ese token. Las peticiones subsecuentes se hacen con el token del usuario.

Puedes ahorrarte un paso si generas de antemano un token para la APP que expire en 20 años y lo dejas en duro. De una u otra forma, alguien puede revisar la petición de tu app y conocer ese token, así que las llamadas a los endpoints abiertos que quieres restringir están protegidas sólo por [oscurecimiento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

## Corolario

Sea que uses JWT u Oauth, puedes hacer el flujo sin tener que mezclar ambos flujos. Mezclarlos complica todo y te obliga a mantener tanto una llave de firma en la configuración como una tabla de tokens. No tiene sentido meterle a la APP lo peor de los dos mundos.

Comment: Gracias Amenadiel por el tiempo que tomaste en responder mi pregunta, quizas me exprese mal. En este momento estoy usando JWT pero mi inquietud surgio al ver que mis endpoints no estan protegidos cuando se acceden a sectores que no requieren autenticación. Lo que quiero es que solo tenga acceso mi API un Cliente autorizado (Ej Angular) al margen de si esta ingresando a un sector el cual requiere un usuario autenticado, es por eso que me pregunte si debería cambiar a oauth2, para validar que cliente tiene permiso para usar los recursos de la API al margen de si un usuario esta logueado. Gracias